# Yii2 ajax validation in popup

Tags: php, yii2

I created a register popup for register new user by rendering the form.

```
   $model = new User();

            ?>
                <?= $this->render('//user/_form', [
                'model' => $model,
                ]) ?>
```

But I cant enable the ajax validation for the form.

**My view**

```
 <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\User */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="user-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([

    'id' => 'register-form',
    'action' => 'user/save',
     'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validationUrl' => 'user/validate',
]); ?>
 <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="txt-fld">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'User Name'])->label(false) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="txt-fld">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'User Email'])->label(false) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="txt-fld">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true,'placeholder' => 'User Password'])->label(false) ?>
    </div>  
    <div class="txt-fld">

        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-new-2 hvr-float-shadow' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("beforeSubmit", "#register-form", function () {
        // send data to actionSave by ajax request.
        return false; // Cancel form submitting.
    });

    </script>
```

I enabled the validation in my form but not working...when I tried to validate its redirect to create page.

**My controllers**

```
    public function actionValidate()
{
    $model = new User();
    $request = \Yii::$app->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost && $model->load($request->post())) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
public function actionSave()
{
    $model = new User();
    $request = \Yii::$app->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost && $model->load($request->post())) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ['success' => $model->save()];
    }
    return $this->renderAjax('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**My model**

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_name', 'user_email', 'user_password', 'user_type'], 'required'],
        [['user_created_at'], 'safe'],
        [['user_type', 'user_status'], 'string'],
        [['user_name', 'user_email', 'user_avatar'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['user_first_name', 'user_last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['user_password'], 'string', 'max' => 200]
    ];
}
```

Comment: try: `Yii::$app->request->isAjax` in controller.

Comment: Not working ..I am trying to enable this in a pop up...When I added this it killed my styles...

Comment: have you some javascript error (firebug console) ?

Comment: Can you disable client validation in active form and try once please  'enableClientValidation' => false.